# Clear CefGlue Browser history

Tags: .net, wpf, chromium-embedded, cefglue

I'm using [Xilium.CefGlue](https://bitbucket.org/xilium/xilium.cefglue/wiki/Home) browser for WPF. How can I clear browser history? I didn't found any managed API for that. I found only method definition in [cef_browser_capi.h](https://bitbucket.org/fddima/cefglue/src/3ea4ac5c3fd9733122139fbd24dff9b66dd52446/third_party/chromiumembedded/include/capi/cef_browser_capi.h).

Answer (score 1):

Currently only one way exist - delete cache path directory when it is no more used by application.

PS: For general CEF questions better ask questions at CEF forum http://www.magpcss.org/ceforum .

Comment: Will it delet whole cache or only the history?

Comment: CEF for now not track visited url and history. So you can delete only cached content (may be also appcache, etc). If you need clear only one thing - check how them are stored - usually differents subsystems uses different files.